# How to sort out the height property in this example?

Tags: html, css, height

I am having a problem setting the height attribute for the content within a modal window.

I want the content within the modal window to be 100%, but the problem is that it is only going as high as about 30%. Why is this happening and how can I get the content within the modal window be able to fill the modal window, and not fill about 30% and thus enabling a scroll bar?

Below is the width of the modal window which is fine:

```
#simplemodal-container {height:75%; width:50%;}
```

Below is the height and width of the iframe:

```
$.modal('<iframe src="' + src + '" style="border:0;width:100%;height:100%;">');
```

And finally below is the content going into the modal window (I did set this height to 100% but then I could not get it to work so it currently has no height property:

```
<div id="previouslink">
<button type="button" id="close" onclick="return parent.closewindow();">Close</button>
<h1>PREVIOUS QUESTIONS</h1>

<p>Search for a previous question by entering in a phrase in the search box below and submitting the phrase</p>

<form action="previousquestions.php" method="post" id="modalform">
      <p>Search: <input type="text" name="questioncontent" value="<?php echo $questioncontent; ?>" /></p>
      <p><input id="searchquestion" name="searchQuestion" type="submit" value="Search" /></p>
      </form>

</div>
```

You can view the modal window by accessing this [link](http://helios.hud.ac.uk/u0867587/Mobile_app/QandATable2.php) and then clicking on the plus button.

Thank you

Comment: The iframe is 100% height, and the body of that iframe is 100% height, so setting `#previouslink { height: 100% }` in iframe's css file doesn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this style:

```
#simplemodal-data {height: 100%}
```

Comment: That is correct. I have one little question before I mark your answer. I have updated the url so you can see for yourself but why when the model window is open, that it shows the scrollbar and that the user can scroll a tiny bit up and down, I thought height was 100%. Is there a way where if the content has gone over 100% height then display scrollbar else don't show the scrollbar at all?

Comment: But will this be consistent across different screen sizes if I change it to 96%, or could it work on 96% for this small laptop screen and it maybe a different value for a bigger laptop screen?

Comment: I really can't tell, I've laptop with screen resolution 1368x768. But as this is issue with height, I think it will work. But you should try it on different sizes of monitors. Use media queries for fall-back support.

Answer (score 0):

This can happen if the document body is itself not filling the window - the document height is less than the window height.  Usually, the solution is something like this:

```
body {
  padding-bottom: 1500px;
}
```

Or it may not be a problem once you take your code into a real environment, where the document is always taller than the window.